# Best way to start sshd in a C program

Tags: c, sshd

I need to start the SSH Daemon from a C program, and currently I am using `system("systemctl start ssh")` (I'm on Raspberry Pi OS). Is there a cleaner way to do it without using `system`?

Comment: You can use `fork()` and `exec()`, but `system()` is fine for simple commands like this.

Comment: Agree with Barmar.  You basically have four options: (1) `system`, (2) `popen`, (3) `fork` + `exec`, or (4) some library CLI that does the same thing that the command-line `systemctl` does.  Sometimes it's worth searching for a way to do (4), but here I'd say, there's nothing wrong with (1).

Comment: @SteveSummit I think the DBUS C-API would be programmatic equivalent. But I agree, it does not seem worth it in the case where this would be the only interaction with it

Comment: I voted to close because we really need to know what you're trying to do. `systemctl` binds you to `systemd` which is still pretty controversial. If your program is responsible for managing sshd you should really manage it yourself.